# Passing command line arguments when profiling with llvm-prof

Tags: llvm

How can I pass command line arguments to my program when profiling with llvm-prof?

And where can I find a more comprehensive documentation for llvm-prof? "llvm-prof -help" output is too brief. Its manual is even shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you write the question implies that you are trying to execute your program using `llvm-prof`. However I am not sure if that is the way to do it. The way to profile is first to instrument your code with counters using:

```
opt -disable-opt -insert-edge-profiling -o program.profile.bc program.bc
```

Then execute the instrumented program using `lli` as follows:

```
lli -O0 -fake-argv0 'program.bc < YOUR_ARGS' -load llvm/Debug+Asserts/lib/libprofile_rt.so program.profile.bc
```

Note the way to pass the arguments to the program using `-fake-argv0 'program.bc < YOUR_ARGS'` above. This step will generate `llvmprof.out` file which can then be read with `llvm-prof` to generate the execution profiles as follows:

```
llvm-prof program.profile.bc
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend staying away from `llvm-prof` at this point. The reason is that it was actually removed from trunk LLVM a month ago (in revision 191835). Here is the commit message that should clarify the motivation:

> ```
> Remove the very substantial, largely unmaintained legacy PGO
> infrastructure.
>
> This was essentially work toward PGO based on a design that had several
> flaws, partially dating from a time when LLVM had a different
> architecture, and with an effort to modernize it abandoned without being
> completed. Since then, it has bitrotted for several years further. The
> result is nearly unusable, and isn't helping any of the modern PGO
> efforts. Instead, it is getting in the way, adding confusion about PGO
> in LLVM and distracting everyone with maintenance on essentially dead
> code. Removing it paves the way for modern efforts around PGO.
>
> Among other effects, this removes the last of the runtime libraries from
> LLVM. Those are being developed in the separate 'compiler-rt' project
> now, with somewhat different licensing specifically more approriate for
> runtimes.
> ```